# Reference to undeclared plugin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I've upgraded my site from v2.3.1 to v2.3.6 and I now get the error:

Reference to undeclared plugin with name 'priceIndexUpdater'

in my system.log.

I've found that in vendor\magento\module-inventory-catalog\etc\di.xml there is the line

```
    <plugin name="priceIndexUpdater" disabled="true"/>
```

Why is the plugin disabled when it is needed. Any ideas what will happen if I delete the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed on this pull request: https://github.com/magento/inventory/pull/3167

Comment: Aha! Thanks for pointing me to this. I'd noticed that commenting out that line stopped the message but I was concerned it might have unintended consequences. Funny that disabling something causes a problem! :o)

Comment: No problem. I had the same issue and drove me nuts for a few days until a guy on the Magento Slack channel sent me that link.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Magento 2.3.6-p1 and the pull request file change from git dont work for me

I copied vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog/etc/di.xml

removed plugin name="priceIndexUpdater" disabled="true" on line 39 and
type name="Magento\InventoryIndexer\Indexer\SourceItem\SourceItemIndexer"
plugin name="priceIndexUpdater" type="Magento\InventoryCatalog\Plugin\InventoryIndexer\Indexer\SourceItem\PriceIndexUpdater" sortOrder="20"/ on line 23 - 25

(my file had priceindexupdater on two lines, the file is a little bit different than in the pull

to app/design/frontend/xx/xx/Magento_InventoryCatalog/etc

did setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, c:f, c:c

But the system.log still gives this error every 30 sec or so. How can I disable it?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're overwriting the core file. Edit that and try it out. That's how I did it (I was lazy) and I have to remember to edit it each time I do an upgrade.

Comment: Hello @PedroKTFC thanks for your answer. You mean you changed the vendor/magento/... directly? Will it not be deleted every time you even just flush cache or something? Thank you

Comment: No. I overwrite the core file, rebuild my shop, flush all cashes and go!

Comment: Hello, you mean you changed this file and keep this path: vendor\magento\module-inventory-catalog\etc\di.xml or where in your custom theme folder did you place the new file?

Comment: I changed the file.